# How to plot data (Var1 vs Var2 as a line plot) containing large number of factors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have some data of the following form:

```
Factor  Var1  Var2
1       100   1.5
2       150   1.2
3       90    1.9
......
1       80    2.0
2       96    2.1
3       50    2.9
```

I have to compare the variation in Var2 with Var1 for the different factors. The idea is to figure out the range of values in Var1 corresponding to which there are low values in Var2, and for which factor.
I have up to 32 factors.

What is the best way to go about this?

So far, I have implemented this as a line plot in ggplot (see figure below).

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = df$var1, y = df$var2, colour = df$Factor)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.05) + 
  geom_point(size=0.8) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5)) + 
  labs(x='var1', y='var2')
```

[image: ggplot Figure]

However, the figure is very cluttered, and it is difficult to make out the patterns for the different factors, especially because of the colour coding as a gradient.

I also tried to use different shapes for the points.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = df$var1, y = df$var2, colour = df$factor)) +  
  geom_line(size=0.05) + 
  geom_point(size=0.8, aes(shape=factor(df$Factor))) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5)) + 
  labs(x='var1', y='var2')
```

But this gives a warning message (see below), and does not show symbols for all the factors.

```
 # Warning messages:
 #    1: The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate; you have 29. Consider specifying shapes manually if you must have them.
```

What is the best way to visualize this variation in the data? The number of factors can vary (maximum 32).

** As suggested, I tried out facet_wrap (see fig below).

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = df$var1, y = df$var2)) + geom_line(size=0.05) + geom_point(size=0.8) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5)) + facet_wrap(~ df$Factor) + labs(x='var1', y='var2') #+ geom_hline(yintercept = 2)
```

[facet_wrap fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDMJ5.png)

For the sake of comparison among the factors, I would like to add a horizontal line to all the plots. But geom_hline(yintercept = 2) does not do the trick, gives the following error msg:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(6L, 8L, 24L, 26L, : replacement has 1170 rows, data has 1
```

How to add a horizontal line to all these plots?
Alternately, is there a way to separate the data frame into smaller data frames, consisting of 5-6 factors instead of all, and plot for each of these smaller sets?

Comment: `facet_wrap(~Factor)`?

Comment: if not, consider `plotly::ggplotly`, where you can interact with the final plot to either zoom into specific section, or section specific factor by double-clicking on the legend.

Answer (score 0):

If your factor levels has an intrinsic order maybe it is better to plot them as a gradient, as if they were numeric:

```
df$Factor_numeric <- as.numeric(gsub("2MCT ", "", Factor))
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = var1,
           y = var2,
           colour = Factor_numeric) +  
  geom_line(size=0.05) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(name = "Your Factor",
                        labels = function(breaks)  paste0("2MCT ", breaks)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5)) + 
  labs(x='var1', y='var2')
```

Another option is to use a new column in the data frame that groups your Factor so you end up with less plots:

```
df$grouped_Factor <- NA
df$grouped_Factor[df$Factor %in% paste0("2MCT ", 101:108)] <- "G1"
df$grouped_Factor[df$Factor %in% paste0("2MCT ", 109:118)] <- "G2"
df$grouped_Factor[df$Factor %in% paste0("2MCT ", 119:124)] <- "G3"
df$grouped_Factor[df$Factor %in% paste0("2MCT ", 125:132)] <- "G4"

ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = var1, y = var2, colour = Factor)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.05) +
  geom_point(size=0.8) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5)) +
  facet_wrap(~ grouped_Factor) +
  labs(x='var1', y='var2')
```

Comment: I tried grouping the factors and plotting. However, the colours are assigned in gradient form, So it is difficult to clearly compare, from the graph , which factor has higher values of Var2 for a given range of values of var1. Is it possible to specify the colours, or use different symbols?